# When i use post request and have response (true) i have error then undefinded, why?

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
UserProfileApi.putProfile(this.state.selectedShoe, this.state.selectedWear, this.state.dreams, this.state.newAvatarPhoto, this.state.Sports).then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
        })
```

[image]

i have `MyProfilePage.jsx?8853:156 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

I have only (true) answer when 200 Ok
How i can solve this problem ? 
[image]

this is another file UserProfileApi.js here all request etc
[image]
my axios now look like

```
 `axios.put(`${envApiUrl}/UserProfile/personalData`, formData, config).then(response => {
                console.log('win', response);
                return 'winner';
            });`
```

[image: there is something strange]

Comment: Where does `UserProfileApi.putProfile` come from ?

Comment: @GaëlS check please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putProfile` function does not return anything therefore, if you do `putProfile(..).then`, you indeed try to call `.then` on nothing.

To fix it, in `putProfile` add a `return` statement, line 279: 
`return axios.put(...)`

Comment: `.then(response => {
    return response.data
   });` 
but it doesnt helped t o me

Comment: Yes, it should fix the error you have `MyProfilePage.jsx?8853:156 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: @gibor nope it's wrong, `.then` does not return the actual value. From MDN: `The then() method returns a Promise.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: can i use some `setTImeout` for `.then` ???  i see i have a problem like then undefinded when request still pending

Comment: @stackerLoki it doesn't make sense. If request is pending, the promise should not be resolved and `.then` should not get called. share with us what changes you made to code and where exactly you get that error

Comment: @stackerLoki also, please share the `MyProfilePage.jsx` code also, since the error seems to come from there. maybe you're missing something in there

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem: you try the define a `.then` block on a function that does not return a promise :)

You got 2 options:

1. transform the `putProfile` function to return a promise- `return axios.put(...)`.
   NOTE: you should remove then inside `.then` clause in this. This `.then` is redundant, as you can just get the same response value in the outside `.then`.
2. move then `.then` you wanted to put outside to inside the `putProfile` function. This could only happen if you do not need to use anything outside of the `putProfile` function in the intended `.then` clause.

Comment: `.then(() => {
    return 'winner';
   });` doesnt helped to me(

Comment: @stackerLoki  did you remove the `.then` inside the function? after the `axios.put`?